# Why is my Axios POST request returning Error 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, swagger

I've got a problem with sending POST request to a backend server (managed by Swagger UI).
Below is the code snippet of POST function:

```
    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const employee: IEmployee = {
          age: newEmployeeData.age,
          id: newEmployeeData.id,
          name: newEmployeeData.name,
          position: newEmployeeData.position,
        };

        axios
          .post("http://34.140.193.23/api/employees", JSON.stringify(employee), {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          })
         .then((res) => setEmployeesData([...employeesData, res.data]))
         .catch((error) => {
           console.log("Error:", error);
         });
    };
```

When I call handleSubmit function, it throws me an error to the console like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (createError.js:16:1)
at settle (settle.js:17:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

When I try to debug in Sources panel in Chrome DevTools it doesn't even return value for res variable. To be precise, it doesn't run .then statement at all.

Backend server: http://34.140.193.23/swagger-ui/#/employee-controller

Am I missing something? Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Wrong content type? Try `application/text` without JSON processing, if it reaches the `then` callback.

Comment: You don't need to stringify the data with axios. Are you sure your employee data is correct? Are age and id numbers instead of strings?

Comment: Also position is an enum and can only be [ BACKEND_DEVELOPER, CEO, FRONTEND_DEVELOPER, PRODUCT_OWNER, SCRUM_MASTER ]

Comment: Yes, the enum solution was right. Thank your for you help.